# Check the app orientation in iOS (not the device orientation)

Tags: ios, swift

Until now, I used to use this code to check if my device is in a portrait or landscape mode:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation)){
           //portrait

}else {
          //landscape        
}
```

But I discovered that this variable check the real position of the device in the 3D space. So if my iPad or iPhone is in a portrait mode and I put it on a table, parallel to the ground, the orientation will not be considered as portrait.
Is there a variable or something similar that can I check to know the orientation of the app and not the physical orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation`: The current orientation of the app's status bar.

Comment: I'll try but I found this question and he say that this method doesn't work properly in case of a split view (I have 3 split view in my app): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769432/app-orientation-in-ios9-split-view

Comment: That's not how I read this. What he's saying is that even while landscape is correctly reported, his layout needs to behave like portrait because of split screen multitaksing.